# Behavior of an exception iside a jspInit method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is provably a very noob question, I´m trying to understand the generated servlet by a jsp file.

This is my code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%!
    public void jspInit(){
    System.out.println("inside the init method");
    int x = 10 /0;
}

public void jspDestroy(){
    System.out.println("destroy");  
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

I dont understand why it's showing  sometimes the exception before the outputs, the message  "inside the init method" is printed 3 times by request (maybe is trying more than once?), and if an exception is raised why the jspDrestroy() method is not called.

Comment: Division by 0 should be giving you a compiler error; so it shouldn't be running at all.

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch I'm running in a tomcat v8 with eclipse luna and is compiling 
the browser shows a 
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero exception  report.